# How to include formatting in a string?

Tags: c#, string, fonts

I need to create string in the following form :-

> Contains **(1) 11.35kg** package of Chips Carob-Malt Sweet Non-Dairy.
>
> **Product features:**
>
> -New
>
> -Organic

As you see, the string I want contains a few bold substrings, underlined strings as well as newlines (as shown).

Please suggest some way of doing this.

I just want to save many strings in the above format to a .csv file and upload them straight away from .csv file to the website where they will be displayed.

Comment: Is this for a web application or a windows application?

Comment: Add the technology you use to display. There is no generic way to format strings with fonts or in your case formatting.

Comment: A *string* is just a chain of characters: a *text*. It cannot contain formatting.

Comment: I need to make strings in the following format so that I can save them in a .csv file and can upload these strings from the .csv file to the website to display..

Comment: I believe the website will have to handle this formatting part

Comment: CSV does not inherently support text formatting. Is this CSV used for anything other then transferring the data into a web site? How is the data in the CSV extracted and used in the website (please post the code)?

Comment: @Daniel : I am using a shopping cart software which demands to make .csv file for bulk import.They don't say anything about formatting , But I need to format the strings so as to display them properly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to save the bold parts between [b] and [/b] like MSN Plus! does. Than your website has to display these parts bold, [u] parts undelined and so on.
 There is no other way of saving formatting in a string then using some kind of markup.

Answer (score 2):

```
string.Format("Contains <b>({0}) {1:0.00}kg<b> package...")
```

or something close to that...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using off-the-shelf shopping-cart software then you need to look into the documentation for that software to determine whether you are able to affect the display of the content. If you can change the formatting it is most likely achieved via some kind of templating system separately from the data import mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Try a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970779.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If it is a web app try http://ckeditor.com/